# Displaying data using angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've a different data structure, which I need to display it via `mat-table`.

```
dataSource= [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Here, `dataSource[0]` is always the heading. rest of the array items are it's row.

So the output of the above data should be like below

**1 2**  `Heading of the table`

3 4

5 6

is the above data structure possible using `mat-table` ? Please help

Note:- I've looked into the mat-table documentation, but i could find anything that helps me

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this, you need to extract the values of column names and separate it from the data.

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  data = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
  dataSource = this.data.splice(1);
  displayedColumns: string[] = this.data[0].map(value => String(value));
}
```

Bind these dataSource and column names in your template dynamically.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{displayedColumns[0]}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{displayedColumns[0]}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[0]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{displayedColumns[1]}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{displayedColumns[1]}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[1]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Please find the working stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmnymd

Answer (score 0):

To create completely dynamic table based on the data you have . You can do below :

in `component.ts` file :

```
public data: any[] = [['age', 'height'], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
  public dataSource: any[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = [];
  isDataReady: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.data[0];
    let tempArr = this.data.slice(1, this.data.length);
    tempArr.forEach((el: any[]) => {
      let obj: any = {};
      el.forEach((key, i) => {
        obj[this.displayedColumns[i]] = key;
      });
      this.dataSource.push(obj);
    });
  }
```

and then  in `component.html` create the table `columns` as below :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="col">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{col}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[col]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

here is the working example : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kj8qhv)